# Angular subscribe loses actual class type

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

When my service method's `subscribe` runs I'm getting back an object instead of the actual class, and I can't figure out why.  I've created a method in my service that returns an actual class based off of the JSON, vs. just the json interface:

```js
getById(id: number): Observable<DetailsForLabAndCaller> {
    return this.http.get<DetailsForLabAndCaller>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}/new`).pipe(
        tap(x => DetailsForLabAndCaller.fromJson(x))
    );
}
```

And my `fromJson` method looks like this:

```js
static fromJson(json: any): DetailsForLabAndCaller {
    const ret: DetailsForLabAndCaller = Object.assign(new DetailsForLabAndCaller(), json);

    ret.me = WorkerInfo.fromJson(ret.me);
    ret.lab = Lab.fromJson(ret.lab);

    console.info(`fromJson: has lab type: ${ret.lab instanceof Lab}`);
    console.info(`fromJson: has WorkerInfo type: ${ret.lab.delegate instanceof WorkerInfo}`);
    console.info(`fromJson: returns a DetailsForLabAndCaller: ${ret instanceof DetailsForLabAndCaller}`);

    return ret;
}
```

When the service is called I see each of those console messages return `true`.  However, when I then try and consume that service, I'm just getting an `object` back, not an actual class object:

```js
this.spaceService.getById(id).subscribe(obj => {
    console.info(`Call returned a real class: ${obj instanceof DetailsForLabAndCaller}`);
```

That console message, which prints after the first three, is saying `false`.  Why am I just getting a vanilla object back at this point instead of the actual class?

Comment: Just do     const ret: DetailsForLabAndCaller = Object.assign(new DetailsForLabAndCaller(), obj) after receiving the result or some duck-type checking

Comment: You probably want to use `map` instead of `tap` in `getById`.

Comment: @fridoo That worked, thank you.  I don't fully understand why tap doesn't work here though because that service call is subscribed to, so it seems like the `tap` would work as well.  If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `tap` in `getById` which just passes the incoming value through and is generally used for side effects. So the returned value from `DetailsForLabAndCaller.fromJson(x)` is never used. To actually map to the returned value you have to use `map`.

```
getById(id: number): Observable<DetailsForLabAndCaller> {
    return this.http.get<DetailsForLabAndCaller>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}/new`).pipe(
        map(x => DetailsForLabAndCaller.fromJson(x))
    );
}
```